# ajax upload image and store in gridfs

Tags: ajax, mongodb, gridfs

the doc of native mongoDB driver about gridfs is just push a local file to gridfs,

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/reference/gridfs/streaming/

how do I get the file submitted by multipart/form-data form of ajax ?

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: @PsioniaX I have not do file system work before, I was thinking about upload the file through 'multer' or something to store the file in server first and then use the path after uploading to push it into gridfs, is it a practical way?